# ¿Cómo hacer update de los datos xlrd? Luego del save no cierra realmente el libro

Tags: python, python-2.7, xlrd

Tengo un problema al usar [xlrd](/questions/tagged/xlrd) con el valor de una celda específica.

Obtengo el valor original:

```
stock=int(hoja.cell_value(rowx=(indice+1), colx=2))
```

Lo modifico y lo sobrescribo en la planilla:

```
tex=int(resta)
rb = xlrd.open_workbook('Data\Articulos.xls',formatting_info=True‌​)
wb = copy(rb)
ws = wb.get_sheet(0)
ws.write(indice,2,tex)
wb.save('Data\Articulos.xls')
```

- `hoja` es obviamente la planilla del libro
- `indice` es el entero que indica la fila del artículo cuyo stock se debe cambiar, y
- `resta` es el stock original menos la cantidad vendida.

Si cierro mi programa, queda perfecto, pero si lo guardo y vuelvo a obtenerlo **sin cerrar** el programa, me devuelve el primer valor, el que tenía al abrir el programa.

Creo que el problema es que luego del "save" no cierra realmente el libro.

¿Cómo logro que haga una especie de update de los datos?

Comment: Si no puedes copiar el código, por lo menos escribe una simplificación del problema en donde podamos replicar el error. De lo contrario es muy difícil ayudarte.

Comment: Hola @MartinLiporace. Bienvenido a [es.so]. Por favor agrega sólo el fragmento del código **relevante** para la pregunta. Y en caso de que realmente sea tan extenso, crea una simplificación del problema: [mcve]

Comment: Ok, a ver si sirve.
PARA OBTENER EL DATO:

stock=int(hoja.cell_value(rowx=(indice+1), colx=2))

PARA MODIFICARLO Y GUARDARLO:
tex=int(resta)
      rb = xlrd.open_workbook('Data\Articulos.xls',formatting_info=True)
      wb = copy(rb)
      ws = wb.get_sheet(0)
      ws.write(indice,2,tex)
      wb.save('Data\Articulos.xls')

("hoja" es obviamente la planilla del libro, "indice" es el entero que indica la fila del artículo cuyo stock se debe cambiar y "resta" es el stock original menos la cantidad vendida). Creo que el problema es que luego del "save" no cierra realmente el libro

Answer (score 1):

`xlrd` es para leer ficheros excel. Si además quieres escribir deberías instalar `xlwt`. Otra opción es usar `openpyxl`.

Te dejo un ejemplo usando `xlrd` y `xlwt` visto [aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16561370/5216568):

```
import xlwt
import xlrd

workbook = xlrd.open_workbook('input.xls')
sheet = workbook.sheet_by_index(0)

data = [sheet.cell_value(0, col) for col in range(sheet.ncols)]

workbook = xlwt.Workbook()
sheet = workbook.add_sheet('test')

for index, value in enumerate(data):
    sheet.write(0, index, value)

workbook.save('output.xls')
```

Comment: Lo sé, y además de xlwt también estoy usando xlutils, pero el problema es solo al leer, por eso me referí solo a xlrd en el título de la pregunta.

Comment: `xlrd` solo lee. De hecho, el objeto `rb` o `wp` (su copia) no deberían tener el método `save`,... Para guardar usa `openpyxl` o `xlwt`.

Comment: Como dije más arriba que para guardar uso xlwt. Creo que no está claro cuál es el problema. Gracias por intentar ayudar de cualquier forma

Comment: Entonces, claramente te falta código. Ponlo completo para que no demos palos de ciego. Con el código que pones es imposible reproducir el comportamiento.

Comment: Es extremadamente largo y no tengo tiempo para perder realizando otro programa a modo de ejemplo. La pregunta creo que fue clara aún sin ejemplos: cómo se puede hacer para que xlrd vuelva a leer una celda que ya fue modificada sin cerrar el programa o en su defecto, cómo cerrar el libro una vez realizada la modificación